# Blackberry Httpconnection Request Timeout issue

Tags: web-services, blackberry, httpconnection

I am facing issue related to Httpconnection request timeout (**not response timeout**).

When i am trying to connect with the server via application i am getting response code **408 or 502** but the same url is working on the blackberry default browser (**plz not that this happen only in the 3G network**).

And this issue not reprodusing each and every time but it occurs 70 % times.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

408 Request Timeout
The server timed out waiting for the request.[2] According to W3 HTTP specifications: "The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time."

502 Bad Gateway
The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server.

So I am guessing some sort of proxy/gateway needs to be set in your application (as may be set in your default BB browser).

Cheers!

Comment: Ya. i have checked all that thing.
But thing is that it doesn't reproduce every time.
For example before 2 hours it gives response code 408 or 502, but now its working fine.

Comment: Ok...If it bothers you again, perhaps you could next look at running a protocol analyzer (Wireshark) and looking at the HTTP communication. This should yield more information on the problem.

Comment: And one more thing, when i am changing the server url then its working fine.
So what is the problem?

Comment: From what to what was the URL changed?

Comment: Sorry to say but it is confidential.

Comment: Ok..you found the probable key to your question - check the hosting provider and google it for similar errors. Good luck!

Comment: If you have access to server side - try to use https. It could be possible that traffic filtered or blocked on the carrier side. maybe some important cookies are not delivered to server.

Comment: @Eugen Martynov: Same error code (408) after applying the changes suggested by you.

Comment: Could you confirm that you use https on the client and server side both

Comment: @Eugen: finally i have moved my web-service to other hosting server. And now every thing is working fine.

thnx for your interest